# eth1 and eth1:0 take different times to echo ping requests?

Tags: linux, ping, ifconfig

When I ping 2 different IPs that go to eth1 and eth1:0 on the same server, the ping time is the same but the time it takes for the ping result to appear in the terminal is much longer with eth1:0. For instance it takes maybe half a second between ping result output for eth1, but more like 4 seconds between ping result output for eth1:0.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the IP didn't have a PTR record.

Answer (score 0):

IP routing on the stack may be the issue.
ARP table on the switch.

Hard to tell without more information.